# With single serializedName annotation can we map to two different data types

Tags: android, gson

```
{
     @serializedName("items")
     private ArrayList<String> items;
}
```

and

```
{
     @serializedName("items")
     private ArrayList<SomeClass> items;
}
```

How can i map to these two using single serializedName ?

Comment: why do you need two data types?

Comment: @IshitaSinha data coming from API response siblings have different types data with same key value

Comment: You can use generics. Like `ArrayList<T> items;`

Comment: @IshitaSinha then how can i access child attributes of SomeClass

Comment: something like this?

`SomeClass item = items.get(i);

int oneAttribute = item.yourAttribute;`

Comment: Ok cool. Thank you for help @IshitaSinha

Comment: @IshitaSinha but this method wont map child attributes